# Can a SQL non-equi join task (example below) be done (faster and /or neater) using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with 3 columns: pid ( a  job) , starttime  (time when it starts ) and fintime (time when it ends)  as made up below:

```
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table(pid=sample(1:100,100), starttime = sample(1:100,100)/100)[,fintime:=starttime + round(runif(100)/4,2)]
```

I need to identify all possible TWO jobs that can be done sequentially  but confirming to  an acceptable “gap” between the Jobs. I can do this using SQL  for a gap between 0.05 and 0.4 units(of time)  as below:

```
require(sqldf)
res <- sqldf("select a.pid as first, b.pid as second , a.starttime as startime,  b.fintime as fintime 
    from  dt a, dt b 
    where  a.fintime < b.starttime - 0.05
       and a.fintime > b.starttime - 0.4
  ")
```

How can I do this using data.table ?
(I am hoping for a performance improvement   over sqldf when the data is large and with more constraints)

Comment: You could try adding indexes to one or both tables and check if that speeds up the SQL query.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks for the sugestion. For a larger data (10K initial observations when It takes about 20 seconds for the sql to run),  I did : `sqldf("create index idx on dt(starttime,fintime)") ` and it did not show improvement.

Comment: That's because it will overwrite the database with a new database each time you call `sqldf`. See the examples on the home page for info.

Comment: `system.time(res <- sqldf(c("create index idx on dt(starttime,fintime)","select a.pid as first, b.pid as second , a.starttime as startime,  b.fintime as fintime 
        from  dt a, dt b 
        where  a.fintime < b.starttime - 0.05
           and a.fintime > b.starttime - 0.4
      ")))`  was 20.4 sec vs 20.3 w/o the index - no improvement

Comment: `starttime` only appears as part of an expression so it can't figure out how to use the index. `fintime` should be first or else rearrange your expression so that `starttime` is alone on the left side. One can't be sure that that will help but it might be enough to allow it to use the index.

Comment: I see - Wow! Now that did it! - the time is under a second now: 0.3 sec ( from 20 s) `system.time(res <- sqldf(c("create index idx on dt(fintime, starttime)","select a.pid as first, b.pid as second , a.starttime as startime, b.fintime as fintime from dt a, dt b where a.fintime < b.starttime - 0.05 and a.fintime > b.starttime - 0.4 ")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is a data.table approach that is about 20X faster, **but** there are some caveats (described at the end).

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)  # for reproducible example
n <- 100     # simple example
dt <- data.table(pid=sample(1:n,n), 
                 starttime = sample(1:n,n)/n,2)[,fintime:=starttime + round(runif(n)/4,2)]
# sqldf approach
require(sqldf)
f.sql <- function(dt) {
  sqldf("create index idx on dt(starttime,fintime)")
  res <- sqldf("select a.pid as first, b.pid as second , a.starttime as starttime,  b.fintime as fintime 
    from  dt a, dt b 
    where b.starttime >= a.fintime + 0.05
      and b.starttime <= a.fintime + 0.4
  ")  
}
res.sql <- f.sql(dt)

# data.table approach with foverlaps(...): need >= 1.9.4 for this!!
packageVersion("data.table")
# [1] ‘1.9.4’
f.DT <- function(dt) {
  lookup <- dt[,list(second=pid, fintime, a=starttime,b=starttime)]
  setkey(lookup,a,b)
  DT      <- dt[,list(first=pid, starttime, a=fintime+0.05,b=fintime+0.4)]
  J.olaps <- foverlaps(DT,lookup,type="any",nomatch=0) 
  J.olaps[,list(first,second,starttime,fintime)]
}
res.DT <- f.DT(dt)
```

So this uses the `foverlaps(...)` function in the newest version of `data.table` (1.9.4). Suppose you have two data.tables, `x` and `y`. Each has a pair of columns that form a range. `foverlaps(...)` finds all combinations of records in `x` and `y` where there is overlap between the range in `x` and the range in `y`. Here we set this up so that `x` has range defined by `fintime+0.04` and `fintime+0.5`, and `y` has range defined by `starttime` at both ends. So now `foverlaps(...)` looks for any combination of records where the starttime is between 0.04 and 0.5 more than the fintime.

Now for the caveats:

First, this only works (AFAIK) if you are willing to relax your constraints to a *closed* interval (e.g., `b.starttime >= a.fintime + 0.05`, vs. strictly `>`).

Second, the data.table approach finds all the records found in the sql approach *plus some additional records*. You can see this with the following code:

```
indx  <- data.table(first=res.sql$first,second=res.sql$second,key=c("first","second"))
setkey(res.DT,first,second)
extra <-  res.DT[!indx,]
```

The extra records seem like they are legitimate, so the question is: why are they not found by `sqldf(...)`? I can't answer that.

Third, this works for your example, but might not be easy to extend with "more constraints".

Finally, here is a "benchmark" with a dataset more similar to your actual data:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4   # more realistic example
dt <- data.table(pid=sample(1:n,n), 
                 starttime = sample(1:n,n)/n)[,fintime:=starttime + round(runif(n)/4,2)]
system.time(res.sql <- f.sql(dt))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   45.25    0.53   45.80 
system.time(res.DT  <- f.DT(dt))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    2.09    0.86    2.94
```

Comment: jihoward, had a quick look. Looks great! Discovered a bug while working on it. Fixed and testing it. Working on caveats as well. Will update this answer then.

Comment: @jihoward , this is nothing short of amazing! Thank you much!

Comment: `The extra records seem like they are legitimate, so the question is: why are they not found by sqldf(...)? `  I checked several mismatches they all lie on the boundary - they should have qualified the "=" must be some numeric representation thingy.

Comment: Fixed the bug [in this commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/62bff083d764956e863c6b08b2573852906ffce9). Should be available soon on 1.9.6. For `>=` and `>`, you can just add/subtract `.Machine$double.eps` start/end intervals accordingly, but yes it's not straightforward. Will see what we can do about it. +1.